# gopls in VSCode is showing "index out of range" BrokenImport errors for imports

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gopls

I've been working on a Go project in VSCode and yesterday gopls in started showing errors like

```
could not import github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/storage/azblob (import failed for "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/storage/azblob": import failed for "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/storage/azblob/blob": internal error while importing "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/storage/azblob/blob" (runtime error: index out of range [581] with length 7); please report an issue) compiler(BrokenImport)
```

for a number of Azure/azure-sdk-for-go imports. The imports themselves are fine (everything compiles, etc.) so I assume it has to do something with gopls.

I've tried reinstalling gopls, Go itself, VSCode, resetting Go environment variables, VSCode settings. Nothing worked.

I don't believe this is similar to something like [Go Modules importing issue in VSCode ("cannot find package [...] in any of [...]")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67763356) and I couldn't find any references to the "index out of range" BrokenImport errors while googling.

I'm on Linux.